# PLSQL or SSRS, How to select having all values in a group?

Tags: sql, oracle, reporting-services, plsql, ssrs-2008

I have a table like this.

```
ID NAME VALUE
______________
1   A    X
2   A    Y
3   A    Z
4   B    X
5   B    Y
6   C    X
7   C    Z
8   D    Z
9   E    X
```

And the query:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 T WHERE T.VALUE IN (X,Z)
```

This query gives me

```
ID NAME VALUE
______________
1   A    X
3   A    Z
4   B    X
6   C    X
7   C    Z
8   D    Z
9   E    X
```

But i want to see all values of names which have all params. **So, only A and C have both X and Z values, and my desired result is:**

```
ID NAME VALUE
______________
1   A    X
2   A    Y
3   A    Z
6   C    X
7   C    Z
```

How can I get the desired result? No matter with sql or with reporting service. Maybe "GROUP BY ..... HAVING" clause will help, but I'm not sure.

By the way I dont know how many params will be in the list.

I realy appreciate any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard approach would be something like

```
SELECT id, name, value
  FROM table1 a
 WHERE name IN (SELECT name
                  FROM table1 b
                 WHERE b.value in (x,y)
                 GROUP BY name
                HAVING COUNT(distinct value) = 2)
```

That would require that you determine how many values are in the list so that you can use a 2 in the `HAVING` clause if there are 2 elements, a 5 if there are 5 elements, etc.  You could also use analytic functions

```
SELECT id, name, value
  FROM (SELECT id,
               name,
               value,
               count(distinct value) over (partition by name) cnt
          FROM table1 t1
         WHERE t1.value in (x,y))
 WHERE cnt = 2
```

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to structure these "sets within sets" of queries as an aggregatino.  I find this is the most flexible approach:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.name in (select name
                 from t
                 group by name
                 having sum(case when value = 'X' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
                        sum9case when value = 'Y' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
                )
```

The subquery for the `in` finds all names that have at least one X value and one Y value.  Using the same logic, it is easy to adjust for other conditions (X and Y and Z,; X and Y but not Z and so on).  The outer query just returns all the rows instead of the names.

Comment: This is also a helpful solution, but I am sending parameters from SSRS as a list, so I can not use X and Y seperately. And the number of parameters in the list is unknown. Thanks anyway.